# Start a fragment from actionbar tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to call a fragment from another fragment that is inside an actionbar tab? How do I do it?

Obviously:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Maps.class));
```

will not work.

I would like to **call:**

```
public class Maps extends Fragment implements GoogleMap.OnMyLocationChangeListener
{
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,   Bundle savedInstanceState) 
   {

    if (rootView != null) 
    {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) rootView.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(rootView);
    }
    try 
    {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
    } 
    catch (InflateException e) 
    {
        /* map is already there, just return view as it is  */
    }

    fa = getActivity();


    if (initMap())
    {

            gps = new GPSTracker(fa);
            curlat = gps.getLatitude();
            curlong = gps.getLongitude();
            gps.stopUsingGPS();
            //Get the ZOOM working for given location.
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"Sorry! Map not available!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    return rootView;
}

private boolean initMap() 
{
    if (googleMap == null)
    {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        googleMap = mapFrag.getMap();
        googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);
    }

    return (googleMap != null);
 }

}
```

my Maps XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutforMap"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**from:**

I have list of items in this class on Item Click I am trying to open the maps fragement.

```
public class Friends extends Fragment 
{

View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_friends, container, false);

list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.friends_list);


   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            Maps fragment = new Maps();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }); 
  return rootView;
 }
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried the following:

```
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new Maps();

            if (fragment != null) 
            {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
            }
```

I am getting error in getFragmentManger();

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager to android.app.FragmentManager
```

Let me know!

Thanks!

Comment: Your Map fragment is using Fragment class from support library. import android.app.Fragment in map class and remove existing import

Comment: @Sayem: Nope. It is not using Support library. It is using right version. anroid.app.Fragment in my Map Fragment

Comment: please check the answer second.

Comment: and if you use android.app.FragmentManager than in some devices issue with app fragment so we use support fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it by using `FragmentTrasactions`

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, yourFragmentInstance, yourFragmentTag);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: What is fragmentTag here?

Comment: just a string for your reference,

you dont need to use it,
but you can get the fragment instance by using that tag

Comment: It would be helpful if you can add an example. for all the constants you have added there inside ft.add

Comment: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/06/android-fragment-transaction-fragmentmanager-and-backstack.html

Comment: dont use import with v4

Comment: I am using FragmentPagerAdapter for my other Action tab.. For which I require v4.

Comment: then use getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: If I I am using getSupportFragementManager(); then I can't use fragment = new Maps();

Comment: @ SHASHIDHAR MANCHUKONDA : I get Type mismatch: cannot convert from Maps to Fragment

Comment: Maps should extend v4.Fragment

Comment: If I do that I end up getting: The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Maps)

Comment: use support fragment in map class & use supportFragmentManager as "FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();" to use the map fragment. in your app use consistency of fragment.

Comment: I now get No view found for id 0x7f0a001a (com.ylg.main:id/map) for fragment Maps{435e2398 #2 id=0x7f0a001a

Answer (score 2):

put your code into your `**Friend fragment**`.

```
public android.view.View onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater inflater,
            android.view.ViewGroup container,
            android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);

        list=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listId);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                Map fragment=new Map();
               ((yourActivity)getActivity()).replacefragment(fragment);


            }
        });

        return view;

    };
```

in your activity create one method like following.

```
private void replacefragment(Fragment fragment){

android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity()
                            .getSupportFragmentManager();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager
                            .beginTransaction();

                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: @ Dilavar: I have the same code. What is the difference? Can you explain? I am trying open Maps Fragment from Friends Fragment.

Comment: @ Dilavar: What do you mean youractivity? Do you mean Friends in this case? if so I tried it says Cannot cast from FragmentActivity to SharedFriends

Comment: public class Maps extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleMap.OnMyLoc

Comment: in map fragment use FragmentActivity and then override oncreate method and in that setcontentView(R.layout.yourLayout)

Comment: @ Dilavar : Instead I had already implemented UP navigation. Hence I just called NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(getActivity());  - This works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You use fragment of **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**
and you use the `getFragmentManager()`; it is return android.app.FragmentManager instance.
But you use `getSupportFragmentManager()` Its works Fine.

replace This code

```
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new Maps();

            if (fragment != null) 
            {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
            }
```

Comment: I now get No view found for id 0x7f0a001a (com.ylg.main:id/map) for fragment Maps{435e2398 #2 id=0x7f0a001a}

Comment: please put your java file